# Weird numbers showing up next to Google Analytics Keywords

Tags: google-analytics

There are some weird numbers showing up next to the search keywords in my Google Analytics account. Please see the attached for reference. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks so much.

[Screenshot 1 link](http://cl.ly/image/0K1b053P132d)

[Screenshot 2 link](http://cl.ly/image/1G3x3g320Y0K)